# Trying to call an MVC controller on IIS7 from URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I deployed my asp.net mvc2 .net4 web application at a win2k8 32bit server with iis7. Doing exactly the same as I have done in the past on 64bit servers that were a bit more up to date patch-wise. However it does not seem to be calling the controllers correctly. When I call the following controller;

> http://localhost/getPlaces?placeID=3498
>   I get a 404 not found error.

I used process monitor to monitor what was going on. What that picks up is;

> CreateFile
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\getPlaces\web.config
>
> CreateFile
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot\GETPLACES

And nothing else. To me that seems very strange.

The web application is located in the wwwroot directory, and the application pool is correctly set to .net 4.x (being an mvc2 .net4 app).

Is there anything obvious I missed? Pretty much everything else in the IIS configuration is default.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: You are specifying a value as a querystring.  Is this correct?

Comment: what do your routes look like? what does your controller action for this look like?

Comment: Well, seeing as this exact whole MVC application actually works on two other IIS7 servers right now, I'm not too worried about those things. I'm slightly more worried that it could be something with IIS not knowing where to look for the controllers. Using procmon I can see that it does not access anything in the web application, it seems to look for / try to create a web.config file under a getPlaces directory. While the truth is that the controller is in wwwroot\controllers, but this should somehow be mapped so that the web application knows where to look for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it was missing the ISAPI filters, I reinstalled .net4 using the repair option, rebooted and all was fine. Thanks for the effort though you who posted :]

Answer (score 1):

The URL doesn't seem valid, are you sure it's not http://localhost/getPlaces/3498 or http://localhost/getPlaces?postcode=3498?

In it's current shape and assuming a default routing setup the URL will get mapped to `getPlaces` action method with a sinle parameter called `3498` (since its a name-value pair without the value). Since an identifier cannot start with a digit in .NET languages, it's not possible.

Comment: ah good point, and my bad, I was just simplifying too much, the call is actually getPlaces?placeID=3498, sorry, making the edit